# How to make setSelection a Spinner with BaseAdapter?

Tags: android

I have a Spinner using BaseAdapter with some Objects. I want to do select an Object correctly but I can't do it.

How could I do setSelection in my Object ?

**Object**

```
public class Estado{
   private Integer id;
   private String estado;
}
```

**BaseAdapter**

```
public class EstadoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private Context context;
    private List<Estado> lista;


    public EstadoListAdapter(Context context, List<Estado> lista){
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Estado estado = lista.get(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.estado_cidades_listadapter, parent, false);
            viewHolder.llEstadoCidades = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llEstadoCidades);
            viewHolder.tvEstadoCidade = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEstadoCidade);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.tvEstadoCidade.setText(estado.getEstado());
        return convertView;
    }



    //holder pattern
    private static class ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout llEstadoCidades;
        TextView tvEstadoCidade;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
Spinner spinEstado = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.acEstado);

Estado est1 = new Estado(1, "SP");
Estado est2 = new Estado(2, "MG");
Estado est3 = new Estado(3, "RJ");

List<Estado> list = new ArrayList<Estado>();
list.add(est1);
list.add(est2);
list.add(est3);

EstadoListAdapter adapter = new EstadoListAdapter(this, list);
spinEstado.setAdapter(adapter);

spinEstado.setSelection(est2);
```

Comment: what happens? Does the code compile?

Comment: @Blackbelt jiu-jitsu ? ..kk ! so, I can't do setSelection in my Object programatically.

Comment: what you mean by *I can't do setSelection* ? I quickly checked the documentation. There is no `setSelection(Object)`, so your code should not compile. What happens if you use `spinEstado.setSelection(est2.id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the index of your object to `setSelection(int)` method and not the object. You can retrieve the index from your List with `list.indexOf(est2)`. In your case, it will be :

```
spinEstado.setSelection(list.indexOf(est2));
```